# Module pip not recognized

Tags: pip

I need help to work on this challenge.
I have python 3.10.6 (latest version) installed on my pc.
during the installation I added path of course.

I want to work with flask.
Python "Scripts" is added to path.
in cmd
`pip help` gives "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

I try to open the python Script folder, It only contains one file called "virtualenv.exe"
I try to uninstall and reinstall python several times. But my problem

`'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` persist.

in cmd:

```
get-pip.py
returns  No such file or directory.
```

and

```
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

```
    C:\Users\fomey>py -m pip install --upgrade pip
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\fomey\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\fomey\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\fomey\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (22.2.2)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\fomey\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\fomey\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\fomey\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\users\fomey\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
```

Please,
What am I not doing?

Comment: How did you isntall python?

Comment: I right clicked  on python-3.10.6-amd64.exe and run it as administrator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: I finally installed a new operating system